# ESLint disable localStorage and sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, eslint

Is there a way to configure ESLint to throw an error when the code uses `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`?

This is needed as I use a third party library for the storage, and I want all the storage to be done through it.

I already tried searching for a plugin, with no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an [ESlint plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-no-storage) that alerts on every use of sessionStorage and localStorage.

Comment: It might be a bit out of scope but what is the use-case for such a plugin? I do not see why it should not be allowed to use local- or sessionstorage. Is there a big downside to using this?

Comment: Sure @Bram. My project uses a third party library to manage the session/local storage (handle corner cases, emulate it when it doesn't exist, etc.). Because of that I want to enforce that all uses of the storage will be made through that third party library, and not directly.

Comment: Another use case: since localStorage/sessionStorage can be turned off in the browser (think incognito mode/all cookies turned off), direct accesses to these constructs is not safe. Instead, a wrapper around these constructs should be used to prevent errors when they're not available. In that case, direct usages except within the wrapper should be prevented.

Answer (score 1):

ESLint doesn't currently have a rule for this. `id-blacklist` will only prevent you from creating variables/function with the names specified. There are two open proposals for rules that would allow you to do this: [`no-restricted-globals`](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/3966)
and [`no-restricted-properties`](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/3218).
But you could easily create a plugin that would do this, just copy `no-alert` rule and change the names to `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `no-restricted-syntax`, if you want to forbid all `localStorage.method()` calls.

```
'no-restricted-syntax': [
  'error',
  {
    selector: "CallExpression[callee.object.name='localStorage']",
    message: 'Do not use `localStorage` directly, use the storage wrapper instead',
  },
  {
    selector: "CallExpression[callee.object.name='sessionStorage']",
    message: 'Do not use `sessionStorage` directly, use the storage wrapper instead',
  },
],
```

Comment: This works if the code uses `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` but doesn't catch it if it uses `window.localStorage` or `window.sessionStorage`.

Comment: You can change the AST selector to match your needs, see the docs: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/developer-guide/selectors

Comment: So others don't have to redo the work. To make `window.localStorage` work, you'd use this selector: `"CallExpression[callee.object.object.name='window'][callee.object.property.name='localStorage']",`